# How to figure out at which position a string contains another string?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Is there a method that could tell for a string like "foo bar Foo Bar one two three" at which position the string "Foo" is contained, case sensitive?

Comment: In what language, there is more than one way to do this.

Comment: The question is tagged as iphone so Objective C.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `rangeOfString` method in [`NSString`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/rangeOfString:) is what you're looking for. Apple has a [document](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/SearchingStrings.html) that has a bit more detail.